# Python Log rotation with max file size doesn't backup log file and stops logging

Tags: python, logging, file-permissions, python-logging

I have a python script which is called by ZoneMinder like 300 times per day. ZoneMinder runs as the user `www-data` on a Raspberry Pi 4. That's why my python script is owned by the user `pi` and the group `www-data`. User `pi` is member of `www-data`.

The log rotation works until the max bytes are reached. I expect that the log file (`google_drive_upload.log`) is backupped (e.g. `google_drive_upload.log.1`) and a new log file is created but since the log file reached the maximum size I lose new log entries. There are no new log entries since two weeks.

My python script is this:

```py
from os import environ as os_env
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import subprocess
import sys
from typing import Union, Dict

import requests
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path
import logging
from logging.handlers import QueueHandler

# logger
log_format = logging.Formatter(
    "%(asctime)s.%(msecs)04d %(name)s[%(process)s] %(levelname)s %(module)s:%(lineno)d -> %(message)s",
    "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S",
)
logger = logging.getLogger("google_drive_upload")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

console_handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
console_handler.setFormatter(log_format)

logger.addHandler(console_handler)

file_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(Path(__file__).parent / "google_drive_upload.log",
                                                    maxBytes=10_000_000, backupCount=3)
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
file_handler.setFormatter(log_format)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

# a lot functions here and logger.debug() calls
```

Is it maybe a permission error? I deleted `google_drive_upload.log` manually to see if it's created again automatically. It's not. I think that's the problem. My script or system can't create a new log file or backups of it. Everything works if I create the log file manually and change its user/group to pi/www-data until the max size is reached.

## Edit 27.01.2023

It has to be a permission issue. I deleted the log file and executed my python script as ZoneMinder would do it:

```
pi@raspberrypi4zm:~/zm-scripts $ sudo -u www-data ./google_drive_upload.py 8008
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/zm-scripts/./google_drive_upload.py", line 61, in <module>
    file_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(Path(__file__).parent / "google_drive_upload.log",
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/logging/handlers.py", line 153, in __init__
    BaseRotatingHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding=encoding,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/logging/handlers.py", line 58, in __init__
    logging.FileHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode=mode,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 1142, in __init__
    StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 1171, in _open
    return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding,
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/pi/zm-scripts/google_drive_upload.log'
```

The permissions are:

```
pi@raspberrypi4zm:~/zm-scripts $ ll
total 44
drwxr-xr-x 3 pi www-data 4096 Jan 27 11:50 ./
drwxr-xr-x 9 pi pi       4096 Jan 12 00:35 ../
-rwxr-xr-- 1 pi www-data  161 Jan 12 00:52 .env*
-rwxr-xr-- 1 pi www-data  106 Jan 12 01:06 .env_example*
drwxr-xr-x 8 pi www-data 4096 Jan 26 15:05 .git/
-rwxr-xr-- 1 pi www-data   66 Jan  5 03:06 .gitattributes*
-rwxr-xr-- 1 pi www-data 2762 Jan  5 03:06 .gitignore*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi www-data 8295 Jan 26 13:36 google_drive_upload.py*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi www-data   36 Jan  5 03:06 README.md*
```

## Edit 2: Solution

Finally fixed by setting correct permissions.

`drwxrwxr-x 3 pi   www-data  4096 Jan 27 12:15 zm-scripts/` where the Python script is inside. And inside of this repository:

```
pi@raspberrypi4zm:~/zm-scripts $ ll
total 88
drwxrwxr-x 3 pi       www-data  4096 Jan 27 12:15 ./
drwxr-xr-x 9 pi       pi        4096 Jan 12 00:35 ../
-rwxr-xr-- 1 pi       www-data   161 Jan 12 00:52 .env*
-rwxr-xr-- 1 pi       www-data   106 Jan 12 01:06 .env_example*
drwxr-xr-x 8 pi       www-data  4096 Jan 26 15:05 .git/
-rwxr-xr-- 1 pi       www-data    66 Jan  5 03:06 .gitattributes*
-rwxr-xr-- 1 pi       www-data  2762 Jan  5 03:06 .gitignore*
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 12003 Jan 27 12:16 google_drive_upload.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 24859 Jan 27 12:12 google_drive_upload.log.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi       www-data  8295 Jan 27 12:13 google_drive_upload.py*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi       www-data    36 Jan  5 03:06 README.md*
```

Sorry. Had to edit this here. Can't answer my own question.

Comment: Seems to me that your guess could probably be it (file writing permissions).
Code looks fine to me.
For debugging purposes, could you run a python script that creates a file and writes to it? (Using basic python `with open(..., 'w') as file:`)

Another debug method that would come to mind is trying some higher logging level statements (like `logger.error("test")`). I sometimes had issues where the logging level would be stuck at the default logging level info

Comment: After recreating the log file manually I forgot to `chmod g+w google_drive_upload.log` so I had a lot of permission errors. It's obviously a general permission error. But how can I solve this? My python script should create this log file and its backups automatically.

Comment: I dont know the ZoneMinder framework or the environment it runs in, but what I would imagine is, that you need to give the script the necessary permissions. On linux you have user id's (`id` command) and you should determine the user that executes your script (see [here](https://linuxhandbook.com/linux-file-permissions/))

Comment: @Engensmax Thanks for your input. I had to think more out of the box. I will edit my question. Can't answer.